# Custom badges not appearing on GitLab project repository UI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I'm trying to show custom badges like code coverage, commits, pipeline status, etc on my GitLab project repository UI using jobs that I created like below:-

```
commits_badge_svg:
  stage: badges
  image: $DOCKER_IMAGE
  script:
    - echo "Creating Commits badge"
  after_script:
    - pip install anybadge
    - commits=$(git rev-list --all --count)
    - anybadge -l commits -v $commits -f commits.svg -c green
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - commits.svg
    when: always
    expire_in: 12 weeks

coverage_badge_svg:
  stage: badges
  image: $DOCKER_IMAGE
  script:
    - echo "Creating Coverage badge"
  after_script:
    - pip install anybadge
    #- coverage_value=${CI_JACOCO_LINE_COVERAGE:-0}  # Use CI_JACOCO_LINE_COVERAGE if set, otherwise default to 0
    - coverage_value=${CI_TEST_COVERAGE:-0}  # Use CI_TEST_COVERAGE if set, otherwise default to 0
    - anybadge --value=$coverage_value --file=coverage.svg coverage
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - coverage.svg
    when: always
    expire_in: 12 weeks

pipeline_badge_svg:
  stage: badges
  image: $DOCKER_IMAGE
  script:
    - echo "Creating Pipeline badge"
  after_script:
    - pip install anybadge
    - >
      if [ "$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE" == "push" ] || [ "$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE" == "web" ]; then
        badge_status=$CI_COMMIT_RESULT
      elif [ "$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE" == "schedule" ]; then
        badge_status="scheduled"
      elif [ "$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE" == "trigger" ]; then
        badge_status="manual"
      else
        badge_status="skipped"
      fi
    - anybadge --label=pipeline --value=$badge_status --file=pipeline.svg passing=green failing=red scheduled=orange manual=blue skipped=yellow
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - pipeline.svg
    when: always
    expire_in: 12 weeks
```

Then I tried to configure the Badge SVG URL's on GitLab Project Settings -> General -> Badges like below:-

```
Link - https://gitlab.com/mycompany/internal/my-project
Badge Image URL - https://gitlab.com/internal/my-project/-/jobs/artifacts/jira-1234branch-adding-code-coverage-badge/raw/coverage.svg?job=coverage_badge_svg
```

I can see my pipeline passing with all these stages and able to generate the SVG files as well. When I browse those SVG Artifacts, the image is fine when I download them however why my SVG is not able to resolve and appearing as badge image through this link?

The custom badges are not able to resolve as shown in this screenshot but if I use any non-custom badges provided by [GitLab](https://gitlab.example.com/%3Cnamespace%3E/%3Cproject%3E/badges/%3Cbranch%3E/pipeline.svg) then it is working
[image]

Comment: the should be present in master or some branch i think not just job